# Conditional Formatting with 2 Sheets not working

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

im trying to mark matching URLs red. 
I have two sheets with URL Data.

My custom Formula looks like this:
`match(A2,indirect(Sheet2!A2:A),0)`

wondering why there is an error if i use `=match(A2,indirect(LostURLs!A2:A),0)`
so with the additional `=`

Anyways both methods are not working and im wondering why?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indirect excepts the first argument to be "a cell reference as string".
So please try

```
=match(A2,indirect("LostURLs!A2:A"),0)
```

and see if that works?

Note: depending on if you want the formatting for a single cell, a column or a row you may have to use a dollar sign in the first argument of the match() function

E.g: If you'd want to repeat the formatting for column A, you would have to use

```
=match($A2,indirect("LostURLs!A2:A"),0)
```

For row 2 that would be:

```
=match(A$2,indirect("LostURLs!A2:A"),0)
```

and for a single cell

```
=match($A$2,indirect("LostURLs!A2:A"),0)
```

NOTE: Depending on your locale, you may have to change the comma's to semi-colons.

Comment: Hey thanks for your fast response!

Sadly this wont work for me...


I copy pasted your help, but as soon as i add the "=" it says "invalid formula" ...
And without the "=" it wont trigger.

I tried even deleting cache etc.

Comment: Try replacing the comma with a semi-colon. The use of comma's or semi-colons depends on your locale. So please try =match($A2;indirect("LostURLs!A2:A");0) and see if that works.

Comment: Your answer was right! I also had to change the "," to ";" due to my locale.
This is a thing you should look out for if you encounter similar problems! :)

Answer (score -1):

perhaps try:

```
=MATCH(A2; INDIRECT("LostURLs!A2:A"); 0)
```